# Increase accuracy through "overfitting" multiple models?

Tags: tensorflow, computer-vision, object-detection

I am currently trying to create a model to classify 5 specific classes from the coco dataset.

I am using the object detection app from tensorflow.

My question is:

Will it be better if i:

**-Train one model to detection all classes at once.**

or:

**-Train one model per class to do really well to find the presence of an item of given class and iterate over each model.**

Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering computation vs accuracy tradeoff -

It will be better to train one model to detect all classes at once because there is a high inter-relation among these tasks. The whole object detection network architecture will remain the same and you just need to change the last layers to make the network detect all 5 classes. This approach will also let your model train faster and you just need to train one single model.

Considering only accuracy -

Training one model per class might help increase accuracy but it totally depends on the dataset and types and number of classes. But you can also end up getting the same accuracy as compared to the first model. Lastly, running 5 models will be 5 times more expensive.

Comment: Thank you! All I needed to know if it would be much more accurate (15%+)but if the difference wouldn't exceed 5-8 % it will probably wont be worth the computation time!